# How to show part of next/previous card RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What is the best strategy to achieve this feature:

[image]

I Have a horizontal RecyclerView with cards.
Each card will fulfil the entire screen, but I want it to show part of the next card and previous one if it has more than one item.

I know I can achieve this by setting my card `android:layout_width` at the adapter to have a specific DP like 250dp instead of `match_parent`. 
But it doesn't look like a proper solution.

This is my code:

Activity with RecyclerView:

```
    class ListPokemon : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val items = createListPokemons()
        recyclerView.adapter = PokemonAdapter(items)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        val pagerSnapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
        pagerSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    }

    private fun createListPokemons(): List<Pokemon> {
        val pokemons = ArrayList<Pokemon>()
        pokemons += createPokemon("Pikachu")
        pokemons += createPokemon("Bulbasaur")
        pokemons += createPokemon("Charmander")
        pokemons += createPokemon("Squirtle")

        return pokemons
    }

    private fun createPokemon(name: String) = Pokemon(name = name, height = 1, weight = 69, id = 1)
}
```

Layout of Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
class PokemonAdapter(val list: List<Pokemon>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PokemonAdapter.PokemonVH>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PokemonAdapter.PokemonVH {
        return PokemonVH(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.pokemon_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PokemonAdapter.PokemonVH, position: Int) {
        holder.textViewName.text = list[position].name
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    class PokemonVH(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var textViewName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName)
    }
}
```

Layout of Adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:padding="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            tools:text="Teste String"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is my result:

[image]

I would like to show part of the next card at this situation. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: use viewpager for it

Answer (score 79, accepted):

What you need to do is set padding to your `RecyclerView`, set `clipToPadding` to `false`, use a `SnapHelper` with it, and you need to make sure the margins on your cards are less than or equal to the padding in the `RecylerView`.

So, let's say you want the distance from the cards to the sides of the screen to be 16dp and you want the distance between the cards to be 8dp. You'll have to set the margins on each card to 4dp, so the total margin is 8dp. And you have to set the padding to 12dp, given there's already a margin of 4dp on each side of the card.

It'll look a bit like this:

Your list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="12dp"/>
```

Your cards:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"/>
```

Comment: Looks great! Thanks.

Comment: What if we need to have variable margins depending on card position, So lets say we can see more of the card next to the first card (so it wont be centered) and rest of the intermediate cards are centered i.e. see equal amount of the cards before and after them and the last card also seems more of the penultimate card?

Comment: @RamPrasadBismil You have to set the margin in onBindViewHolder dynamically based on the position

Comment: What a clever trick! Though I don't understand why `SnapHelper` was mentioned, it's not being used in this solution.

Comment: Works Perfect. Thanks.. Easy solution

Answer (score 1):

I think the padding solution is not a good for all cases, because forces the last item to have padding to the right.

Personally i use runtime width calculation of each item and i am very satisfied with this. So you can do the following:

**onBindViewHolder**

```
if (position == data.size - 1) {
    holder.itemView.layoutParams = RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
} else {
    if (width == null) {
        holder.itemView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
              override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                   holder.itemView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                   width = holder.itemView.width
                   params.width = width!! - partOfPage
                   holder.itemView.requestLayout()
              }
         })
     } else {
         params.width = width!! - partOfPage
         holder.itemView.requestLayout()
     }
 }
```

The outcome is that all middle items are rendered showing a part of the next page, but the last one is rendered full width.

Answer (score -1):

Change your `CardView` width from `"match_parent"` to `"0dp"`. And add,  `layout_weight` as `"80"` (or similar). Make your parent view (`RecyclerView`) `layout_weightSum` as `"100"`.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="80"
```